# JButton not visible in JToolBar when using the Nimbus look-and-feel

Tags: java, swing, nimbus, jtoolbar

I am wondering if anyone can come up with a work-around to the following layout issue I am having with the `Nimbus` look-and-feel.

The issue is that the button in the toolbar is not visible because the `JToolBar` layout manager does not correctly account for the width of the `JTextField`. The `Metal` look-and-feel does not seem to exhibit this bug.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextFieldTest extends JFrame
{
    public TextFieldTest()
    {
        // Create the text field
        JTextField textField = new JTextField( 20 )
        {
            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumSize()
            {
                return super.getPreferredSize();
            }
        };

        // Create the tool bar
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.add( textField );
        toolBar.add( Box.createHorizontalGlue() );
        toolBar.add( new JButton( "Button" ) );

        // Layout the frame
        getContentPane().setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        getContentPane().add( toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH );
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 800, 600 ) );
        pack();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                TextFieldTest test = new TextFieldTest();
                test.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                test.setVisible( true );
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7171632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default layout for JToolBar in Nimbus is:

```
class javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthToolBarUI$SynthToolBarLayoutManager
```

You should set it:

```
    toolBar.setLayout(new BoxLayout(toolBar, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
```

Comment: The only problems with this approach are that (1) the toolbar handle disappears (when its floatable), and (2) you also have to swap to Y_AXIS when the toolbar is dragged to be vertical. But since my toolbar isn't floatable, it doesn't impact me. Thanks for the work-around.